# How to add a value within specific key when extending an interface?

Tags: typescript, types

Let's say I have an interface:

```
interface Person {
  age: number
  name: {
    first: string
    second: string
  }
}
```

And I want to extend `Person` to `Friend`, which would look exactly the same as `Person` but with an added `nickname` value in `name`, like so:

```
interface Friend {
  age: number
  name: {
    first: string
    second: string
    nickname: string | null
  }
}
```

I know I could do...

```
interface Friend extends Person {
  nickname: string | null
}
```

...but this would add it outside of `name`.

I can't figure out any way to achieve this, any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by using the `type` keyword instead of `interface`:

```js
type Friend = Person & {
   name: {
     nickname: string
   }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You can extract name: `{ first: string, second: string }` into a separate interface and extend that.
Ex.:

```
interface Person {
  age: number
  name: Name
}

interface Friend extends Person{
    name: FriendName
}

interface Name {
    first: string
    second: string
}

interface FriendName extends Name {
    nickname?: string
}
```

[TS playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgArQM4HsTIN4BQyycA5hAFzIgCuAtgEbRHVx2XIBybEBAvgQKhIsRCgBiUYBBAATZBAAekORjSYchYsRA8qk6XO7t%20g4dHhIuPfC2IxgUDGCrOpIUneQYICHLNcwd08BIXALMWQDGVljFCUVWTU4221qYAQAa112AH5A4NMCABsIMGR2KnQnHGQAXlTtMg4ARgBmABovHI4tNO0HJxdkACIAKSwACxARrv7tHz85KhGAESwIEa8BNNNS8pgpGJb9I7l6xuJmqna57R6qPvnB5xWAKzgQTbv5xf8V9abbZePZlZCHQyyABMp0hFyeJHIN063T0l36L2G4ymuDGPAwsy8aT%20y1GgMJ8x0GWyaPGYy2aVCfCAA)